# Objective-C equivalent of Python's struct.pack and struct.unpack

Tags: python, objective-c, struct, bit-manipulation, pack

I am trying to convert a python based function to Objective-C and would appreciate the help. I've looked for any resembling questions, but I am not too familiar with byte buffers and would appreciate an explanation, and if possible an Objective-C equivalent operation.

In python:

```
struct.unpack('<Q', struct.pack('<d', 42.6440708))[0] # 0x4042bd7c00000000 
struct.unpack('<Q', struct.pack('<d', -71.04575620000003))[0] # 0xc05e8aae40000000
```

How would I go about trying to implement this in Objective-C? Any help would be appreciated.

The first input `42.6440708` returns a value of `4631198440076690398` in Python. I would like to achieve the same value in Objective-C.

Thanks!

Comment: Since Objective-C is based on C, think about how you would do it C (or search for answers to your question in that domain). For example [_Objective-C Structures_](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_structures.htm).

Comment: Thank you, could you help me understand what the struct.pack is doing in Python? Then I could understand how to create a struct in C/Obj-C.

Comment: Here's the online documentation for [`struct.pack()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack).

Comment: `struct.pack()` converts (or packs) a variable number of values into a single string of bytes according to a format string it is also passed (as its first argument). The format string contains codes which indicate how each value is to be converted into bytes. For example: `struct.pack('i', 42)` would return a byte string containing `\x2a\x00\x00\x00` which represents the value 42 as a 4 byte little-Indian  integer (i.e. `0x0000002a`). It's similar to a `struct example { int value; };` declaration in C.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. Could you help me understand what happens when I pack using 8 bytes 'd' and then unpacking using 8 bytes 'Q'?

Comment: Packing a Python floating point value using format `'d'` stores it as an 8 byte double precision number (type `double` in C). Unpacking that with format `'Q'` results in those same 8 bytes being returned interpreted as an unsigned integer (type `unsigned long long` in C).

Comment: It seems to me that essentially what's being done is what is can accomplished with a `union` in C where the same bytes of memory can be treated a one of two (or more) different data types. i.e. In C given a type declaration of `union Data { double d; unsigned long long Q; };` and a variable of that type declared with `union Data var;`, the same bytes in memory comprising the variable could be accessed either as a `double` floating-point value via `var.d` or as an `unsigned long long` using `var.Q`.

Comment: Check out [_Objective-C Lesson 14: Structs and Unions_](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/objectivec-lesson-14-structs-and-unions/81).

Comment: I was able to get some results. Do you have any idea why the data would be similar, but not exactly the same? I posted my answer below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118048/discussion-between-acenario-and-martineau).

Comment: Sorry, chatting wouldn't be worthwhile, I don't know Objective-C.